# Error when trying to install Protobuf for J2ObjC on the 4th install command

Tags: java, macos, terminal, installation, protocol-buffers

I've been working on this for a day or two now and I can't seem to find clear instructions anywhere on this particular issue:

When I try to build the latest version of protobuf for macOS using the terminal, after running

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
```

I get the following error:

```
Making install in .
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 protobuf.pc protobuf-lite.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
install: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/protobuf.pc: Operation not permitted
make[2]: *** [install-pkgconfigDATA] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I have tried running "make clean" then recompiling, however that doesn't appear to have helped and I cannot seem to find anything online on this error for protobuf. Anyone have any suggestions?

Note: I have tried installing protobuf using Home-brew and that does not appear to work as during the J2ObjC installation it does not appear to be able to locate the root directory for Protobuf

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and solved it.
The problem is that pkgconfig is restricted by mac.
So you need to disable csrutil and you can do that on Mac Recovery mode.

Just follow these links.

1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x

This is to disable that csrutil.

2. https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/mac-recovery-mode-3674052/

This guides you how to enter Recovery mode.

It definitely works. I managed to install protobuf by fixing this issue.